# Log Usage of Particular Programs

Tags: linux, logging

I'd like to be able to log the usage of certain programs on Linux systems. As an example, I'd like to know who's FTP'ing files out of the system or placing files in the FTP dropbox, and if possible only track such activities involving files over a certain size. It would be useful if there was a general purpose approach to such tracking, too.

I've considered, in the case of ftp, just writing a wrapper script around the actual command that would track such things, but this seems inelegant. But I'm unable to find anything in other logging facilities that allow establishing such a watch on usage.

Answer (score 0):

Logging is complex and there are so many aspects of a program that might be considered useful for logging that I find it unlikely that a generic and elegant solution will be found.

`strace` plus `grep` plus something to check e.g. file size, such as `stat -c "%s"` might lead to something interesting. Combinining such tools is one of the strengths of Unix-based systems, and there will probably be several solutions that way.